# Remove td that doesn't have an id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sort of simple problem but can't for the life of me figure it out...

I would like to remove an entire `td` from a `tr` (with its children: `div` with class 'sch', and `a` with an id 'hlp'. However, the td itself doesn't have an id, class, or any other defining characteristics *per se.*

**Code for the `tr`**

```html
<tr>
  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a class="btn" href="?ae=Dialog&amp;t=AddressBook&amp;ctx=1" title="Address Book">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=1" alt="">Address Book</a>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a class="btn" onclick="return onClkOp();" href="?ae=Options&amp;t=Messaging" title="Options">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=2" alt="">Options</a>
    </div>
  </td>

  <!-- ***** To be removed ***** -->
  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a id="hlp" class="btn" href="#" title="Help">
        <img src="https://mail.kgs.org.uk/owa/8.3.298.1/themes/base/help.gif" alt="Help">
      </a>
    </div>
  </td>
  <!-- ********** -->

  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a id="lo" class="btn" href="#" title="Log Off">
        <img class="noSrc" src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=4" alt="">Log Off</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried:
**1.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("td").has(".sch").remove(); //This removes the entire row, which I don't want
});
```

**2.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("td").has(".sch").has("#hlp").remove(); //This doesn't work
});
```

**3.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sch").prev("td").remove();
   $("#hlp").prev(".sch").remove();   //Doesn't work...
});
```

NB: The reason I can't do this directly in my code, or add an `id` to the offending `td` and why it is a table is that I am editing my webmail (OWA) and am not able to physically change the code: I am using browser extensions to add Javascript and CSS, hence why it has to be JS or jQuery (or even CSS if there is a way to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".sch").find('#hlp').closest('td').remove();
```

or as ids are unique so you can directly do this:

```
$('#hlp').closest('td').remove();
```

```js
$('.sch').find('#hlp').closest('td').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a class="btn" href="?ae=Dialog&amp;t=AddressBook&amp;ctx=1" title="Address Book">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=1" alt="">Address Book</a>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a class="btn" onclick="return onClkOp();" href="?ae=Options&amp;t=Messaging" title="Options">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=2" alt="">Options</a>
    </div>
  </td>

  <!-- ***** To be removed ***** -->
  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a id="hlp" class="btn" href="#" title="Help">remove
        <img src="https://mail.kgs.org.uk/owa/8.3.298.1/themes/base/help.gif" alt="Help">
      </a>
    </div>
  </td>
  <!-- ********** -->

  <td nowrap="">
    <div class="sch">
      <a id="lo" class="btn" href="#" title="Log Off">
        <img class="noSrc" src="http://placehold.it/35x35&text=4" alt="">Log Off</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use id of anchor element in has selector to only target desired td element:

```
$('td:has(div.sch a#hlp)').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58g4gq1n/)**

Comment: Strangely, this worked in my JSFiddle, but not on the site. But thankyou for your quick answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

The TD you seek to remove is the third. So if the page structure does not change, you can use `:nth-child` selector.

```
$(tableSelector + ' td:nth-child(3)').remove();
```

(you don't want to cut the third column out of all tables in the page).

Or you can work backwards, and target the `a#hlp`. Then use `.closest()` to find the enclosing `td`, and remove it.

Comment: op wants to target the elements based on id of anchor. this would fail if  td is not nth child.

Comment: Er, it seems to me that he wants to target a specific TD. He has identified the id of one of the childs as *one* way to do that - but it's not the only one. If the page structure stays the same, the element order can be used.

Comment: Sadly, the table in which my `tr` is also doesn't have an id or class. (Outlook Web Mail has tonnes of tables, tables nested in tables... argh...) but good thought, thankyou +1

Comment: For this kind of work you can perhaps use Firebug for Firefox; it has extensions to identify the DOM and CSS path of any element you click on. The path thus obtained *does* need to be worked on, before it can be translated to jQuery selectors, but it is usually a good start.